# I need to make a script, to gather info from 2 files, and sort it in another. Launched from terminal

Tags: shell-script

We have two files `kolokwium1.txt` and `kolokwium2.txt`, they contain names and numbers.

**kolokwium1.txt**

```
Kowalski Jan 3
Nowak Adam 5
Malec Ewa 2
```

**kolokwium2.txt**

```
Malec Ewa 4
Kowalski Jan 2
Nowak Adam 3
```

I want to write a script `scalenie.sh` to create a new file called `kolokwia.txt` from the files `kolokwium1.txt` and `kolokwium2.txt`.

In the new file here will be sorted names and numbers, from lowest to highest:
eg.

**kolokwia.txt**

```
Kowalski Jan 2 3
Nowak Adam 3 5
Malec Ewa 2 4
```

Comment: OK, so what part is giving you trouble? What do you have so far? Why is Malec Ewa shown with 2 and 4 in the output when it is only in one file and has only one value? Why is Nowak Adam shown with 2 numbers instead of three, when the name appears three times?

Comment: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: Hi @Adam. Welcome to StackExchange. You got off to a rough start per the comments on the inaccuracies of your first post. The lessons are: **(1)** do spend time researching your issue, **(2)** show your efforts in solving your problem (what you've done so far), **(3)** be ACCURATE in your phrasing and when preparing your examples.  For instance I could comment: what kind of sorting did you perform on `kolokwia.txt` ? If it's alphanumerical, it's wrong as shown: "Malec" comes before "Nowak".

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
$ head kolokwium{1,2}.txt
==> kolokwium1.txt <==
Kowalski Jan 3
Nowak Adam 5
Malec Ewa 2

==> kolokwium2.txt <==
Malec Ewa 4
Kowalski Jan 2
Nowak Adam 3
```

then using [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html)

```
mlr --nidx sort -f 1,2 -n 3 then \
  nest --implode --values --across-records --nested-fs ' ' -f 3 kolokwium{1,2}.txt > kolokwia.txt
```

produces

```
$ cat kolokwia.txt 
Kowalski Jan 2 3
Malec Ewa 2 4
Nowak Adam 3 5
```

Comment: +1 for referencing `Miller`. I did not know about it and will try it out for quick `json` manipulation in `bash`. On Arch, it is available at: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/miller/

Comment: Seems a very weak assumption, based on a sample of three records, that the names will exactly join without insertions, and there will be one single-digit numeric on each row.

Answer (score 0):

*I used `data1` for OP's file `kolokwium1.txt`, `data2` for OP's file `kolokwium2.txt` and `data` instead of `kolokwia.txt` as output.*

Several ways of doing this. Some rely purely on `awk`. They tend to be more complex to master, as they involve arrays.

Here's a (very ?) simple solution based on `join` on the first column, followed by a selective printing and sorting of numbers using `awk`:

```
$ join -j 1  -t" " <(sort data1) <(sort data2) | awk '$5>$3 {print $1, $2, $3, $5} $3>$5 {print $1, $2, $5, $3}' >| data
$ cat data
Kowalski Jan 2 3
Malec Ewa 2 4
Nowak Adam 3 5
```

Explanation:

- `join` option **-j 1**: join on column 1 of the two input files
- `join` option **-t " "**: use " " (a space) as input and output field separator
- notation `<(sort filename)` is called process substitution. Here the sorting process’ output can be referred to using a filename. Both input files are sorted as `join`requires it. Note that there must be NO space between `<` and the left parenthesis `(` in the process substitution.
- The result of the join is sorted on the first column but not on numbers. Additionally the firstname of each individual is repeated in 2nd and 4th position.
- Pipe the above result in a simple `awk` cmd and conditionally print either fields 1,2,3,5 or 1,2,5,3, depending on whether number in record field 5 is greater than number in record field 3 or vice versa.

HTH